# Web Scraping ou Web Crawler isolar Node

Tags: c#, winforms, aplicação-web, aplicação-desktop, scraping

Por favor, estou tentando resgatar a seguinte informação:

`"value bra": (<span class="value bra">3,666</span>)`

```html
<div class="ticker-financial-market" initiated="true">
   <div class="ticker-slide" style="width: 1446px;">
    <section class="currencies">
 <div class="info">
  <a href="https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/cambio/dolar-comercial-estados-unidos/">
       <span class="name"> Dólar com.</span>
       <div class="numbers">
        <span class="data neg">-0,19</span>
        <span class="value bra">3,666</span>
       </div>
  </a>
 </div>
        </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

Estou tentando com um emulador na internet muito interessante, a saber:
[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8rsuym)

Mas eu não estou conseguindo "ISOLAR" o NODE...
  ... sem retorno de erro, o melhor que eu consegui foi isso:

```
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section[@class='currencies']"))
```

Dessa forma retornou valores, mas NÃO é o que eu quero:

```
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/div/section/div"))
```

O código completo é:

```
using System;
using System.IO;    
using System.Xml;    
using System.Linq;    
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        GetTftd();  
    }

    private static void GetTftd() {
        var url = @"https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/cambio/dolar-comercial-estados-unidos/";
        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

        foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"ticker-financial-market\"]/div[@class=\"ticker-slide\"]/section[@class=\"currencies\"]"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link.OuterHtml);
        }   
  }
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Já tentou usar `//div[@class='value']`?

Comment: Aparece:
Exceção sem tratamento
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Valor não pode ser nulo.
Arg_ParamName_Name'

Comment: Ah pera, dei a informação errada. Seria `//span[@class='value']`

Comment: Também não... o mesmo erro para:
var HeaderNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='value']").ToList();

Comment: Run-time exception (line 18): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

[System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   at Program.GetTftd() :line 18
   at Program.Main() :line 11

Comment: Por favor Sorack, se quiser testar, pode usar o site: "https://dotnetfiddle.net/8rsuym", basta mudar a URL e a NODE.

Comment: Mudar a URL pra onde?

Comment: Mude para: (https://economia.uol.com.br/) ... quero pegar o Dólar Comercial. O emulador ".Net Fiddle" já tem o exemplo pronto, você só precisa apontar para o site que quer resgatar a informação.

Comment: Você verificou se esse valor não é preenchido pelo Javascript?

Comment: Sorack, pelo que eu entendi lendo o site: "https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes" você precisa passar esse valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Também não consegui nesse site, tudo o que está na `<section class="currencies"></section>` não aparece.. tente outro site:

```
var url = @"https://themoneyconverter.com/USD/BRL.aspx";
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='cc-ratebox']");

Console.WriteLine(value.InnerText);
```

Comment: Vik, é preciso pegar a NODE correta (/html/body/section[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h3/a[3]) com essa NODE funciona! Eu não consegui pegar, mas um usuário do VBMANIA (KERPLUNK) pegou e me passou. []'s, Fabio I.